# Rdlc tablix column header not repeating on every page "Repeat column header on every page" is already checked

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Here is my tablix properties

[image]

[image]

[image]

What Am I missing? Please help thanks!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This is particulary tricky using `Tablix`...

Give a look at this link: [what to do when the RepeatColumnHeaders Property in a Tablix isn’t working](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx)

In `Advanced Mode` select the `Static Row Group` you want to repeat and set these properties:

- `.RepeatOnNewPage = True`
- `.KeepWithGroup = After`
- `.FixedData = True`

It is also recommended to set Tablix property `.RepeatColumnHeaders = True` in case Microsoft will release a patch to this strange behaviour.

To get to `Advanced Mode`:

- make sure you can see the row groups and column groups window
- over to the right hand side of the column groups list box, there’s a small downward arrow
- click on this to reveal the `Advanced Mode` check box

[image: advanced mode]

Comment: When the text in any of the column is so large that it move to the next page then the header column will not repeat. Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: I have two headers, I want to repeat top 1 but not the second one, any help on this?

Comment: Some of you might have error while compiling, instead of adding modifications to Column group (Static), try with row groups(Static)..worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Works for me: `RepeatOnNewPage = True`

[image]

Comment: The helpful item in this answer for me was finding where to click for advanced mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new solution I just remembered:

Move your table header to the report Header, sample please see as the picture. That will maker sure your title is repeat in all pages for all situation.
[image]

Comment: This will only help if you only have 1 table in your report. If you have more than one talbe you'll need to go with a different solution

Comment: The report designer won't let me add a matrix / Table to the report header

Comment: I have two headers, I want to repeat top 1 but not the second one, any help on this?