# rdlc Report in VS2015 - Repeating values being suppressed

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have defined a simple report with 6 columns.
Column 1 and 2 represent the groups.
The values of these columns are somehow being suppressed when repeated.
How do I disable this suppression?

Attached is the report output:

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Text box was explicitly set to suppress duplicating values. To change it -  click on text box (table cell) and  press F4. Then, change "HideDuplicates" property to False.
2. These columns were added in the process of adding groups to the table. So, they are "group headers" of a sort. To remove suppressing of the duplicates in this case, delete those columns. Note: be sure to change the following to "Delete Columns Only":

   [image]

   And then re-add two columns to the left of your first column and set their values to appropriate fields values.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. The first one gave me error " The value ‘False’ of the HideDuplicates property of the text box ‘CERT_COY’ is invalid. This value is the name of a group or dataset over which to apply the hiding: it should either be the name of a group containing the current group or, to hide duplicates over the entire dataset, the name of the current dataset." And the second one did not have any effect on the output. Please advise further.

Comment: If you removed those two columns (as suggested in #2) and then added two columns "inside group" as regular columns, not group headers and made sure that "HideDuplicates" is set to False, I don't see how it would not work. You can post xml code for further review.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now the duplicates are seen on each row as I wanted. Thank you, your help is much appreciated. But now the Column Headers Show up only on page one. When I select subsequent pages 2, 3, 4, etc..... none of the pages show the column header, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. 
The solution suggested [here][1] worked for me.
@InitK, Thank you for your help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699635/rdlc-tablix-column-header-not-repeating-on-every-page-repeat-column-header-on-e