# How to have column header printed on each page when printing from Report Viewer

Tags: wpf, reportviewer

I have a simple report using report viewer in my WPF application.  It does not have any sub-report.  The column header does show up on top of each page in the report viewer itself; however, when I try to print it out or save it to a PDF file, the column header only appears on the first page.  Is there a way to have column header be on each page in the printed pages and in save file?

My Row Groups (static) setting is below

- FixedData False
- Hidden False
- HideIfNoRows False
- KeepTogether False
- KeepWithGroup    After
- RepeatOnNewPage True

UPDATE: It turns out that the header does show up in the save file but not on every page.  It shows up on page 1, then page 6 to 12, then disappear on page 13 and not show up until page 20.  The rest of pages are like these, header showing up on some pages but not all.  My report is using legal size paper and Landscape orientation.  Is this a bug in the Report Viewer? I am using WPF .net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: Does this fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699635/rdlc-tablix-column-header-not-repeating-on-every-page-repeat-column-header-on-e

Comment: @J.H. Thanks for the comment but the other question didn't help.  I added the UPDATE part in my question.  Looks like the header shows up randomly on pages. Not sure what is going on.