# How to group all data in RDLC report with header details when page breaking

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I want to group all the data with header section in Microsoft Report viewer(RDLC) reports. I can group tables in RDLC report(Tablix), but when the page break the report header section data related to grouping will display same data. I want to change it as the table grouping.

```
             id 1:  -----header 

             name -abc | age-25   ----detail
```

### page break

```
             id 2:  -----header 

             name -aaa | age-20   ----detail
```

I  want to display data like above

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699635/rdlc-tablix-column-header-not-repeating-on-every-page-repeat-column-header-on-e

Comment: thank you #bruno.almeida# but i want to change the data related to group in the header section.not the table header .i mean report header.

Comment: i see. I have done it once long time ago. I think i had used the advance mode, but don't remember well. Try this: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx